# Limit for character length of a row in command prompt

Tags: python, csv, powershell, command, prompt

I have these functions which return me a dictionary.

```
def zipString2Array(ziplist):
    if ziplist!="-ignored-":
        return ziplist[9:].split(",")
    else:
        return []

def getRegions(quota):
    ## { pid : { rid : [state, ziparray] } }
    regions = {}
    #testing = []
    rows = quota.split("\n")
    for i in rows:
        row = i.split("\t")
        if len(row)>1:
            pid = row[0].strip()
            state = row[10].strip()
            zipstring = row[11].strip()
            ziparray = zipString2Array(zipstring)
            if pid not in regions.keys():

                new = {pid : {"0" : [state,ziparray]}}
                regions.update(new)
            else:
                rid = str(len(regions[pid]) + 1)
                new = {rid : [state, ziparray]}
                regions[pid].update(new)
        #csvfile.close()

            #testing += [pid]

        else:
            pass
    #test = rows[0].split("\t")
    try:
        del regions['Partner ID']
    except KeyError:
        print "exception"
    return regions
```

I am passing that quota file to getRegions function by pasting the input to the command prompt

```
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

# input csv as pasted string
str_quota = ""
stop = ""
print "Paste Partner Quota Report: "
while True  :
    row = raw_input()
    if row.strip() == stop:
        break
    str_quota +="%s\n" % row

# string to csv
csv_quota = StringIO(str_quota)
```

Program runs fine but the issue i am facing its just taking 4094 characters from a row and leaving rest of them. Is there any way i can fix this ?

Comment: Why the powershell tag?

Comment: Because i was using windows power shell to run the program.

Comment: It looked like a pure Python problem. If you are calling python from PowerShell, and think that PowerShell is impacting the script in some way, please add those details. There will be people (like me) who scan this forum for PowerShell questions and won't be sure whether we can help with this question.